# Setting a variable equal to the output of FindRoot

Tags: evaluation, variable-definitions

I define a function $f(x)$ as

```
f[x_] := x*Exp[-x] - 0.16064;
```

Then I set a variable `actualroot` to the function `FindRoot`, starting at $x=3$

```
actualroot = FindRoot[f[x], {x, 3}]
```

and get the output

```
{x -> 2.88976}
```

Later, I want to compare this output with a different estimate ($x\approx -2.88673$) of the root, and calculate error, so I have

```
Abs[(actualroot - estimateroot)/actualroot]
```

and I get this output:

```
Abs[(-2.88673 + (x -> 2.88976))/(x -> 2.88976)]
```

How do I get *Mathematica* to evaluate this expression? I also tried using `N[]` function to give me a decimal evaluation, but it didn't work.

Comment: You can use `actualroot = FindRoot[f[x], {x, 3}][[1, 2]]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The usual way to get the values of the results of `FindRoot`, `Solve`, etc., which are lists of `Rule` is the following:

```
f[x_] := x E^(-x) - 0.16064
actualroot = x /. FindRoot[f[x], {x, 3}]
estimateroot = -2.88673;
Abs[(actualroot - estimateroot)/actualroot]
```

Output:

> 2.88976
>   1.99895

Comment: Thanks, new to mathematica, just diving in

Comment: @DWC well, then it's probably good to know that `/.` is shorthand for `ReplaceAll`. Apart from its doc page reading [this tutorial on transformation rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ApplyingTransformationRules.html) will prove fruitful.